Running Bamboo Jobs inside container
I'm exploring Bamboo  world and currently I'm having problem while running Jobs inside Docker container.
Job is really simple and it contains two tasks:

Repository checkout
Simple bash script with one echo command inside.

For some reason I keep getting error for the second task.
command 16-Jul-2024 19:27:04    Beginning to execute external process for build 'Salesforce - Salesforce-CI - Default Job #41 (SAL-SA-JOB1-41)'\n ... running command line: \nC:\Users\Andrzej\AppData\Local\Temp\runInDocker4074183598377721378.sh C:\Users\Andrzej\Downloads\bamboo\bamboo\temp\SAL-SA-JOB1-41-ScriptBuildTask-15119154021230456187.bat\n ... in: C:\Users\Andrzej\AppData\Local\Temp\n
simple  
16-Jul-2024 19:27:04    Failing task since return code of [C:\Users\Andrzej\AppData\Local\Temp\runInDocker4074183598377721378.sh C:\Users\Andrzej\Downloads\bamboo\bamboo\temp\SAL-SA-JOB1-41-ScriptBuildTask-15119154021230456187.bat] was -1 while expected 0
simple  16-Jul-2024 19:27:04    Finished task 'Script' with result: Failed

I tried to debug it and found out that this runIndocker script copies another script into the container(container script below)
#!/bin/sh
cd 'C:\Users\Andrzej\Downloads\bamboo\bamboo\xml-data\build-dir\SAL-SA-JOB1'
umask 000
'C:\Users\Andrzej\Downloads\bamboo\bamboo\temp\SAL-SA-JOB1-41-ScriptBuildTask-15119154021230456187.bat'
exit $?

I don't know why but it tries to go to my Windows path while being inside container. Could someone help? For now I just want to create container with ubuntu image, clone repository there and run one simple bash script.
